# Restart Tomcat using bat file Windows

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I have a Jenkins script which needs to restart the server after deploying the war file. 
the script has three steps 
`%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\shutdown.bat &&
copy %JENKINS_HOME%\Project\Web.war %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\ && 
%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat`


However, if the system is not running there is error like this:

`Tomcat may not be running. 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

I need a way to restart the tomcat safely even if the server is not running.

Comment: Put the commands on separate lines.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, there is same error.

Comment: Of course there is the same error. Tomcat isn't running, so it can't be stopped. But this way your webapp gets deployed and Tomcat gets started, whether Tomcat was running or not.

Comment: the execution stopped right after the first command. :/

Comment: Not if you put them on separate lines and got rid of the `&&`. If you don't know what it means why are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked after using & instead of &&

The remaining codes get executed even if the first fails if we use & .